# Why KE is not increasing all the time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I could not understand why Kinetic energy of a particle continoulsy does not increase with time when the resultant force in the particle must be parralel to the velocity at all instants .

Source : [Question no. 28](http://www.excellup.com/testntricks/iitPhysics/friction8.aspx)

Comment: Yes it does. A simple way to think about it is,  force produces acceleration which continuously change velocity thus continuously changing the KE. Equivalently, force does some work on the body, and by conservation of energy that is converted to KE of the body continuously.

Comment: Is by any way mass decreasing in the example you are referring? You should have given an example also other wise the question seems wrong

Comment: Or may be  work done might be converted into potential energy! Think about it

Comment: @Utkarshfutous see my answer . I think it is correct reasoning .

Comment: why do you think it does not keep increasing? it does (at least in classical mechanics)

Comment: "when the resultant force in the particle must be parralel to the velocity at all instants" that statement isn't always true at all.  Look at pure circular motion, the force is perpendicular to velocity, which is as far from parallel as it comes.

Comment: @JMac In the question I am discussing about a case .

Comment: @search Then as Utkarsh said in his comment, you should make that clear in your question.  As it stands right now it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @JMac  [http://www.excellup.com/testntricks/iitPhysics/friction8.aspx](Question no. 28)

Answer (score 1):

we say Force can decrease the velocity when force is acting opposite to direction of veclocity . and it is parrallel .

If velocity is decreasing then KE is also decreasing .

Comment: That is Called anti-parallel generally and in the case of parallel there is no such example that I could find